# AndAlso to avoid double "If-Then"

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if I can use "AndAlso" to avoid errors caused by an object "nothing", without using a double "If-Then"
For example, I have this code:

```
Public Sub Main() Handles Btn_Main.Click
    Dim Word As String = InputBox("Insert a word", "Word", "Word")
    Dim mObject As Object = mWord(Word)
    If Not mObject Is Nothing Then
        If mObject.length >= 6 Then
            MsgBox("The 6th char of the word is " & mObject(6))
        Else
            MsgBox("the word is shorter than 6 characters")
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Function mWord(ByVal Word As String) As Object
    Dim mReturn As Object = Word.tochararray
    If mReturn.length > 6 Then
        Return mReturn
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Can I avoid double "If-Then" this way:

```
Public Sub Main() Handles Btn_Main.Click
    Dim Word As String = InputBox("Insert a word", "Word", "Word")
    Dim mObject As Object = mWord(Word)
    If Not mObject Is Nothing AndAlso mObject.length >= 6 Then
        MsgBox("The 6th char of the word is " & mObject(6))
    Else
        MsgBox("the word is shorter than 6 characters")
    End If
End Sub
```

Is it a good way to use AndAlso or not?

Comment: BTW I think this is off topic.

Comment: @roryap Concise and precise answer. If everything was so ... - Why do you think is off topic? Now I can write my code without this doubt.

Comment: Because it's about design.  It's not a programming problem.  It might be better suited to another stack exchange site, possibly [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) though I'm reluctant to point you there because they don't seem to like it when people do that for some reason.

Comment: Either way, you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @roryap I read it, but I still don't thik that my question is off topic (but I can be wrong)

Comment: @roryap - this isn't a good question for programmers as it's more about the implementation than the conceptual aspect of programming.  As to why "they don't seem to like it when people [point you to there]", that's because of the generally low quality of content that self-migrates from SO over to Programmers.  There are many, many incorrect recommendations to re-ask a question on Programmers, and the Progs community actively works to close down those recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a good way to use `AndAlso`, and is what the operator is intended for.

[The visual basic `And`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx) operator performs a Boolean comparison, but does not short circuit the evaluation.

[The visual basic `AndAlso`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) operator performs a Boolean comparison, and short circuits the evaluation.

[Short circuiting the comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx) is useful as it avoids unnecessary operations.  Generally speaking, when performing `If` conditional checks like this, you want to use the short circuiting Boolean operator.  `OrElse` would be the logical corollary to `AndAlso`

Nested `If` statements, as shown in your first example, yield duplicated code and a more difficult to understand (read: follow) logical structure.

Comment: Note that `IsNot` is available e.g. `If mObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso...`